# ¿Por qué no me funciona el flexbox?

Tags: html, css3

Estoy intentando alinear unos ítems verticalmente  pero le doy el `align-items: center;` pero por alguna razón no lo centra, no entiendo cual es el problema.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 8px
}

.flex-item {
  background-color: #042388;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="flex-item"></div>
      <div class="flex-item"></div>
      <div class="flex-item"></div>
      <div class="flex-item"></div>
      <div class="flex-item"></div>
      <div class="flex-item"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba utilizando [`justify-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content).

> La propiedad CSS justify-content define cómo el navegador distribuye el espacio entre y alrededor de los items flex, a lo largo del eje principal de su contenedor.

```css
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 8px
}

.flex-item {
    background-color: #042388;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="flex-item"></div>
        <div class="flex-item"></div>
        <div class="flex-item"></div>
        <div class="flex-item"></div>
        <div class="flex-item"></div>
        <div class="flex-item"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Para más información puedes revisar [Alineando contenido en el eje principal](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container#alineando_contenido_en_el_eje_principal).

Citando un poco el contenido de este enlace:

> Con justify-content controlamos que sucede con el espacio disponible, en caso de que haya más espacio del que se necesita para mostrar los ítems.
>
> La propiedad justify-content  accepta el mismo valor que  align-content.
>
> - justify-content: flex-start
> - justify-content: flex-end
> - justify-content: center
> - justify-content: space-between
> - justify-content: space-around
> - justify-content: stretch
> - justify-content: space-evenly (not defined in the Flexbox specification)

Para el caso de la propiedad [`align-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/align-items), puedes revisar el siguiente link: [El eje transversal](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container#el_eje_transversal)

Un poco del contenido citado:

> Las propiedades align-items y align-self controlan la alineación de nuestros elementos flexibles en el eje transversal, en filas si flex-direction se encuentra en row ó en columnas si flex-direction se encuentra en column.

Para la alineación vertical puedes utilizar [flex-direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction) en este caso utilizando la opción **column**.

> La propiedad CSS flex-direction especifica cómo colocar los objetos flexibles en el contenedor flexible definiendo el eje principal y la dirección (normal o al revés).
>
> Las opciones que podemos utilizar son:
>
> - flex-direction: row;
> - flex-direction: row-reverse;
> - flex-direction: column;
> - flex-direction: column-reverse;

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero necesito alinear los elementos verticalmente y ahí es donde no me funciona.

Comment: Ok, veo que corregiste tu pregunta, enseguida completo mi respuesta. ;)

Comment: @DanielMedina, corregí mi respuesta. ;)

Comment: Muchas gracias @israel-ICM :)